# How to update a table using values from java ArrayList?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I'm working on my application where I want to update my table after email has been sent. I created function that connect sql database and java, also in other class I created function that updates table but what I need is these two classes together. I want to use my array-list after execution for updating of my table.
Here is my code for connection and sending emails:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class TestSendEmails {
    private String emailTo;
    private String emailSubject;
    private String emailBody;
    private String emailAttachments;
    private Integer RecordId;

    public TestSendEmails(){

    }

    public TestSendEmails(String emailTo, String emailSubject, String emailBody, String emailAttachments, Integer RecordId){
        super();
        this.emailTo = emailTo;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
        this.emailAttachments = emailAttachments;
        this.RecordId = RecordId;
    }

    public String getEmailTo(){
        return emailTo;
    }

    public void setEmailTo(String emailTo){
        this.emailTo = emailTo;
    }

    public String getEmailSubject(){
        return emailSubject;
    }

    public void setEmailSubject(String emailSubject){
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
    }

    public String getEmailBody(){
        return emailBody;
    }

    public void setEmailBody(String emailBody){
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
    }

    public String getEmailAttachments(){
        return emailAttachments;
    }

    public void setEmailAttachments(String emailAttachments){
        this.emailAttachments = emailAttachments;
    }

    public Integer getRecordId(){
        return RecordId;
    }

    public void setRecordId(Integer RecordId){
        this.RecordId = RecordId;
    }
}

class TestSendEmailD{
    private Connection con;

    private static final String GET_EMAILS = "Select* From Emails";

    private void connect() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://100.000.000.00\\:3333;databaseName=Test;user=mmmm;password=1234");
    }

    public List<TestSendEmails> getTestSendEmails() throws Exception{
        connect();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(GET_EMAILS);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        List<TestSendEmails> result = new ArrayList<TestSendEmails>();
        while(rs.next()){
            result.add(new TestSendEmails(rs.getString("emailTo"), rs.getString("emailSubject"),rs.getString("emailBody"),rs.getString("emailAttachments",rs.getInt("RecordId"))));
        }
        disconnect();
        return result;
    }

    private void disconnect() throws SQLException{
        if(con != null){
            con.close();
        }
    }
}

class EmailSender{
    private Session session;

    private void init(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "100.000.000.00");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "678");

        session = Session.getInstance(props,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("test@gmail.com", "123");
                    }
                  });
    }

    public void sendEmail(TestSendEmails s) throws MessagingException{
        init();
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(s.getEmailTo().replace(";", ",")));
        message.setSubject(s.getEmailSubject());
        message.setText(s.getEmailBody());
        message.setContent(s.getEmailBody(),"text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    public void sendEmail(List<TestSendEmails> emails) throws MessagingException{
        for(TestSendEmails TestSendEmails:emails ){
            sendEmail(TestSendEmails);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Update code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;

public class UpdateEmail {
  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://100.000.000.00\\:3333;databaseName=Test";
    String username = "mmmm";
    String password = "1234";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.util.Date date = new Date();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      String query = "update Emails set SentOn = ? where Id = ? ";
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
      pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
      pstmt.setInt(2, 200); // In this line I want to use my array-list to update my table.
      pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    } finally {
      pstmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I have to create new connection for my update in my second program and where I should implement my update code. If you know what I should change please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Main.java code:

import java.util.List;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestSendEmailD dao=new TestSendEmailD();
        List<TestSendEmails> list=dao.getTestSendEmails();
        EmailSender sender=new EmailSender();
        sender.sendEmail(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: First `result.add(new TestSendEmails(rs.getString("emailTo"), rs.getString("emailSubject"),rs.getString("emailBody"),rs.getString("emailAttachments"))); `where is the `id` here

Comment: rs.getInt("RecordId")

Comment: where you are stored all these ids.

Comment: Only one ID, rest of them are Strings. I stored them in ArrayList result.

Comment: `s.getRecordId()` while printing this statement whats the output. is it like `id1;id;id3;...`. @user3023588

Comment: I tried this System.out.println((getInt("RecordId"))); and I got null.

Comment: try this `System.out.println(s.getRecordId());` since you already added to `result.add(new TestSendEmails(..`. Check this line.

Comment: I got 6 what is RecordId number. So I think that is correct. Where I should implement my Update code?

Comment: only 6 or multiple while printing the above statmnt. since you are having `while`

Comment: Only 6 because my query has Where clause. Only emails that haven not been send. So that is correct, can you help me with update?

Comment: where you are calling this `sendEmail()`

Comment: I didn't found `sendEmail()` in `main()`

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestSendEmailD dao=new TestSendEmailD();
        List<TestSendEmails> list=dao.getTestSendEmails();
        EmailSender sender=new EmailSender();
        sender.sendEmail(list);
    }

Comment: update in your code that's better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83758/discussion-between-user3023588-and-satya).

Comment: see my answer below. You must take care of `exceptions` also. Since while sending a mail or updating a record `exceptions` may raises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        conn = getConnection();
        java.util.Date date = new Date();

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@gmail.com"));
        String query = "update Emails set SentOn = ? where Id = ? ";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement

        String str[]=String.valueOf(s.getRecordId()).split(";");//id1;id;id3;.... 
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(s.getEmailTo().replace(";", ",")[i]));
        message.setSubject(s.getEmailSubject());
        message.setText(s.getEmailBody());
        message.setContent(s.getEmailBody(),"text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Done");

        pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
        pstmt.setInt(2, str[i]); // In this line I want to use my array-list to update my table.
        pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement
        System.out.println(str[i]+" "+s.getEmailTo().replace(";", ",")[i]+" "+new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));//to check whether its working or not.
      }
```

Its exactly not an exact answer. check whether its working or not. Here you must take care of `exceptions` also. I didn't written that code here.

Comment: Do I need code for connection above this code or not?

Comment: we need get `conn` object. Since its not available.

Comment: I'm getting error on that line, it say conn cannot be resolved.

Comment: now see my code. The above error occurs since you are not declaring `conn` object `Connection conn = null;`

Comment: k. welcome. but you must care of `exceptions` while sending a mail or updating a record. I didn't try here for anything here.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have an ArrayList() called **yourList**. The following code goes before

`String query ...`

```
StringBuilder ids = "";
String prefix ="";
for (Integer id: yourList) {
     append(prefix);
     prefix = ",";
     ids.append(String.valueOf(id));
}
```

change your query to:

```
String query = "update Emails set SentOn =? where Id in (" + ids.toString() + ")";
```

and send only the **SentOn** as parameter:

```
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```